# how to create a org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile out of a org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java

I've been searching the web but cannot find any example.

Having one instance of:

```
org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream
```

How can i obtain one instance of:

```
org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `ByteArrayInputStream`? Otherwise it's logically not possible.

Comment: @LukeLee it's output indeed. I believe i've seen code to pass from inputStream from OutputStream and viceversa .

Comment: Ah, I see. You can get the bytes written to the stream.

Answer (score 3):

`UploadedFile` is an interface and you can simply implement it by wrapping a byte array:

```
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ByteArrayUploadedFile implements UploadedFile {

    private final byte [] data;

    private final String filename;

    private final String contentType;

    public ByteArrayUploadedFile(byte [] data, String filename, String contentType) {
        this.data = data;
        this.filename = filename;
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFileName() {
        return filename;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputstream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getContents() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String filePath) throws Exception {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
            fos.write(data);
        }
    }
}
```

The interface is for representing an uploaded file, so we need to provide additional information like the file name and content type.

Then you can do this to get the instance from a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = ...;
UploadedFile uploaded = new ByteArrayUploadedFile(os.toByteArray(), "SomeFile", "application/octet-stream");
```